# How To download a functioning pdf in django using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: django, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have a django project, where i download the template as a pdf using wkhtmltopdf.The pdf is downloaded when i click the download button, However when i open the pdf it says, **"Error
Failed to load PDF document."** and i cant open the downloaded pdf. Upon looking at the terminal i see this error:  **UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.** What is causing this issue and how can it be solved?

***this is my views.py:***

> @login_required def download_resume(request):
> # Retrieve data from your Django models
> personal_info = personalinfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
> summaries = summary.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
> experiences = experience.objects.filter(user=request.user)
> educations = education.objects.filter(user=request.user)
> certs = certificates.objects.filter(user=request.user)
> skillset = skills.objects.filter(user=request.user)
>
> ```
> # Generate the PDF content using a template
> template = get_template('template0.html')
> context = {
>     'personal_info': personal_info,
>     'summaries': summaries,
>     'experiences': experiences,
>     'educations': educations,
>     'certs': certs,
>     'skillset': skillset
> }
>
> # Render the template with the context data
> html_content = template.render(context)
>
> # Configure pdfkit with the path to wkhtmltopdf
> pdfkit_config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:/Users/lulu/PProjects/resumebuilderproject/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe')
>
> # Convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf
> pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html_content, False, configuration=pdfkit_config)
>
> # Create a response with the PDF content
> response = FileResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
> response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="resume.pdf"'
>
> return response
> ```

***this is my html download button:***

> {%
> csrf_token %}   
>      DOWNLOAD

Comment: Have you tried removing `{% csrf_token %}` from the download button template? Which tutorial are you following (post a link)?

Comment: yes i tried to remove the {% csrf_token %} and exempt it, but still didnt work. not really following a tutorial, ive been using the documentations.

Comment: You can solve it by providing a `csrf_token` in the template context. The documentation should tell you how.